# Set Label properties for Form controls - D365 Finance and Operations - X++

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, finance, x++, dynamics-365, operation

I need to set Label as Bold or Change its Color on Form Control.

There are not much details available for the same on  Microsoft.
I can do the same on control directly but that changes value's styling. I need the same for label text.

Tried but not working:

1. Control.labelForegroundColor(WinAPI::RGB2int(255,0,0));
2. Control.labelBold(7);

Kindly help

Comment: I noticed that the built in "FormGroupControl" are bold. You could use one of those and put your control in it. Then just select "Show Label" to No on your actual control. I don't see a way to make the text bold but maybe you could use one of the available extended  style options. Do you have to do this via x++ or can you use the form designer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Deprecated APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/migration-upgrade/deprecated-apis), which lists the two properties mentioned in the question.

The [history](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/dynamics-365-unified-operations-public/commit/90c1f6b96b1aee1167fa4415ad27e27a2e3e9738) of that article shows that they have been listed there as deprecated since 2017, so it is not surprising that they no longer work.

These properties were available in earlier versions (e.g. AX 2012), but with the switch to a pure browser based client, they are no longer supported.

The article also lists some reasons for the deprecations in the beginning, such as:

> - Not suited/applicable to the new client.
> - Degrade performance.
> - Chatty (cause lot of traffic back and forth between server and client).
> - Redundant (framework automatically handles these now).

Faking it with other controls like @Jason Rowe suggests might work. But my recommendation would be to reevaluate the business requirement behind this customization and check if it can be implemented in a different way that does not require working against the system.

In general, my experience even with earlier versions is that changing colors or other design aspects of the ui is not very well supported and does not align well with the design/ui philosophy of Microsoft for the product.